# How to let the user create many dice?

Tags: c#

So right now, this code can only let you 2 dice ten times, but if i wanted the user to enter any number of dice, how do i do that?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Random numgen = new Random();
        int dice1 = 0;
        int dice2 = 1;

        for (int roll = 0; roll <=10; roll++)
        {
            dice1 = numgen.Next(1,7);
            dice2 = numgen.Next(1,7);
            Console.WriteLine(dice1 + "\t" + dice2);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();


    }
```

Comment: And a loop to gather input, and a loop to produce the output.

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't seem to look like you need to save any of your dice rolls, but rather just output them to the screen I would omit the dice ints.

```
    public void RollDice(int NumberOfDice)
    {
        Random numgen = new Random();
        for (int roll = 0; roll <= 10; roll++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfDice; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(numgen.Next(1, 7) + "\t" + numgen.Next(1, 7));
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```